# Take out value from list and use it

Tags: python

I'm doing a course on python for beginners, and im trying to draw a tree with a list

```
picture = [
  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
]
```

The point is to use the list "picture" to draw the tree, if the  value is 0 the pixel is blank, and if the value is 1, draw.

How would you go about taking out the value and draw?

```
for i in picture:
  for x in i:
    if x == 0:
      print("0", end="")
    if x == 1:
      print("x", end="")
```

I tried this way, but the result is just a long string "000x00000xxx000xxxxx0xxxxxxx000x000000x000"

Comment: What are you really asking? I mean, your code already properly loops over the values in the list, but on the other hand, it doesn't even attempt to convert them into pixels. Please [edit] to clarify. If you only want to add a newline, then just add `print()` at the end of the `for i` loop. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you want more tips.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `print()` at the end of the body of the first loop to move the output to the next line, then it outputs the tree.

```
for i in picture:
    for x in i:
        if x == 0:
          print("0", end="")
        if x == 1:
          print("x", end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
000x000
00xxx00
0xxxxx0
xxxxxxx
000x000
000x000
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for l in picture:
    print(str(l)[1:-1].replace('0', ' ').replace(',', ' '))
```

```
         1         
      1  1  1      
   1  1  1  1  1   
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
         1         
         1
```

Comment: Manipulating string representations is probably not a great learning tool for a beginner. Instead, using a similar idea, you could do `print(' '.join(' ' if x == 0 else str(x) for x in l))`